# Randomly distribute people in groups

Tags: java, arraylist, random, shuffle

I am working on a group generator and using this method to group people

```java
public String nMix(String file, int numOfGroups) {
   ReadFile info = new ReadFile();
   ArrayList<String> studentInfo = info.readEachWord(file);

   List<PeopleClass> people = new ArrayList<PeopleClass>();
   for (int i = 0; i < studentInfo.size(); i += 4) {
      people.add(new PeopleClass(studentInfo.get(i))); //name
   }

   Collections.shuffle(people);
// System.out.println(people.get(0).getName());

   Function<PeopleClass, String> discriminator = PeopleClass::getName;
   AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger();
   List<List<PeopleClass>> groups = new ArrayList<>(people.stream()
      .sorted(Comparator.comparing(discriminator))
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> index.getAndIncrement() % numOfGroups))
      .values());

   //groups.forEach(System.out::println);
   groups.forEach(System.out::println);
   String txt = "";

   for(int j = 0; j < groups.size(); j ++) {
      txt += "Group" + (j + 1);
      txt += "\r\n";
      txt += groups.get(j);
      txt += "\r\n";
      txt += "\r\n";
   }

   return txt;
}
```

My people class

```
public PeopleClass(String name){
   this.name = name;
}
```

But every time I use this, the groups seem to be not random but groups as the order of the original ArrayList of names. How should I fix this and make random.

Comment: Why you call `.sorted(Comparator.comparing(discriminator))` after shuffle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s one way.

```
    final int numOfGroups = 3;

    List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Nielsen", "Jensen", "Hansen",
            "Pedersen", "Andersen", "Christensen", "Larsen", "Sørensen");
    Collections.shuffle(names);
    List<List<String>> groups = IntStream.range(0, names.size())
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i % numOfGroups))
            .values()
            .stream()
            .map(il -> il.stream().map(names::get).collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    groups.forEach(System.out::println);
```

For the sake of a simple presentation I am just distributing strings into groups at random here. It will work the same with `PeopleClass` objects. Example output:

> ```
> [Larsen, Jensen, Sørensen]
> [Nielsen, Christensen, Hansen]
> [Andersen, Pedersen]
> ```

I don’t like stream operations with side effects. This is why in my first stream operation I am working on indices into the shuffled list only, distributing them into groups. This allows me to do the modulo operation without referring to anything outside the stream operation. After I have formed lists of indices, I convert each such list to a list of names in a new stream operation on the result from the first one.

### What went wrong in your code?

As others have said, this line is the culprit:

```
      .sorted(Comparator.comparing(discriminator))
```

You are sorting your folks in a deterministic way, thereby effectively undoing the previous shuffle. This is why you get the same groups each time.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce and run your code and get the expected results. 
I only needed to make a few changes:

1) In your initial for loop, you are incrementing i by 4:

```
for (int i = 0; i < studentInfo.size(); i += 4) {
```

I don't know why you would do that, causing you to skip adding students from your file to the list, so I changed it to increment i by 1:

```
for (int i = 0; i < studentInfo.size(); i++) {
```

2) The Collections.shuffle() call is working as expected and if printing the shuffled list directly after the call you get something like and printing the list, you can see they are properly shuffled.

And finally, you shouldn't be calling `.sorted()` in your Lamda, which will once again order the list, defeating the purpose of the `Collections.shuffle()` call:

```
    Function<PeopleClass, String> discriminator = PeopleClass::getName;
    AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger();
    List<List<PeopleClass>> groups = new ArrayList<>(people.stream()
          //  .sorted(Comparator.comparing(discriminator))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> (index.getAndIncrement() % numOfGroups)))
            .values()
    );
```

Finally, it's also helpful to override the `toString()` method in your `PersonClass` (would be better to just call it `Person`). By overriding `toString()`, you can return just the name of the person, making printing out the entire List readable.

Below is the final modified version of your classes:

```
public String nMix(String file, int numOfGroups) {
   ReadFile info = new ReadFile();
   ArrayList<String> studentInfo = info.readEachWord(file);

   List<PeopleClass> people = new ArrayList<PeopleClass>();
   for (int i = 0; i < studentInfo.size(); i++) {
      people.add(new PeopleClass(studentInfo.get(i))); //name
   }

   Collections.shuffle(people);
   System.out.println("Shuffled people: " + people);

   Function<PeopleClass, String> discriminator = PeopleClass::getName;
   AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger();
   List<List<PeopleClass>> groups = new ArrayList<>(people.stream()
      //.sorted(Comparator.comparing(discriminator))
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> index.getAndIncrement() % numOfGroups))
      .values());

   //groups.forEach(System.out::println);
   groups.forEach(System.out::println);
   String txt = "";

   for(int j = 0; j < groups.size(); j ++) {
      txt += "Group" + (j + 1);
      txt += "\r\n";
      txt += groups.get(j);
      txt += "\r\n";
      txt += "\r\n";
   }

   return txt;
}
```

Person Class:

```
class PeopleClass {
   String name;

   public PeopleClass(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public String getName(){
      return this.name;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return this.name;
   }
}
```

Input: I don't have your input file contents, so using a sample list of: `{"p1","p2","p3","p4","p5","p6","p7","p8","p9","p10"}`

Output:

> Shuffled people: [p8, p4, p7, p6, p9, p1, p3, p2, p5, p10]
>
> Group1 [p8, p6, p3, p10]
>
> Group2 [p4, p9, p2]
>
> Group3 [p7, p1, p5]

Comment: hey I am incrmenting by 4 because my arraylist comprises different information, so that every fourth is the name of the person, sorry I didn’t mention this @pczeus

Comment: The code worked perfectly after getting rid of the sorted!! I think because I copied the same method for some of my other sorting algorithms and forgot to adapt that part!! Thank you for your detailed explanation it really helped!! @pczeus